# Identify the part in Solidworks assembly

Tags: xml, vba, solidworks

I am doing the VBA code to output the properties of assembly and parts into XML file.

I have already done the code about the property of only assembly but for parts, I can't get the individual part in assembly using VBA.

I was trying to get by following method.

```
' here Part_A is a part inside assembly 
Set swComp = swAssembly.GetComponentByName("Part_A")
```

But the error alert is displayed and the value of `swComp` was empty.
So, I can't get the properties of the part anymore.

If there is anyone who know the above reason, please let me know the correct method.

I am trying to get the property name and value of all parts in assembly using VBA macro and to output into  XML file.

Comment: You do not have a "Part_A".  Is "Part_A" the name of an existing part?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Even though I have the part named "Part_A" obviously in assembly, it is displayed that Part_A part is nothing in VBA
I want to know why this happened

Comment: Is swAssembly the parent of Part_A?

Comment: Yeah and thanks for your ask again.
I have just solved myself the issue. In above code, the part name have to be given into "Part_A-1" and I don't know the reason. During I print the debug about component name, I knew the fact casually.
I want to cooperate with you about the Solidworks api using VBA in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already figured out, you need to use "Part_A-1", since the component's names is auto-incremented for each instance of a part in an assembly.

But a better way to get all components in an assembly is to use the [Getchildren](https://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/api/sldworksapi/traverse_assembly_at_component_level_example_vb.htm) function, or [GetComponents](https://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks%7Esolidworks.interop.sldworks.iassemblydoc%7Egetcomponents.html)

Comment: Hi Jeromep, 
Thanks for your kind answer.
I solved successfully the problem to get the components in assembly using GetComponents function and this method help I could reduce amount of the repeated VBA code